# Oracle scheduled job fails

Tags: oracle, jobs, ora-12012, ora-01422

I am using Oracle 10g and using following script to create the job

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE archtemp AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ARCH_TEMP SET ARCH_DATE = SYSDATE; 
    COMMIT;
END archtemp;

VAR jobno NUMBER;
BEGIN
   DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(:jobno, 'archtemp;', SYSDATE, 'sysdate + 1/1440');
   COMMIT;
END;
```

The job never executes automatically (though it runs manually) with following error in `alert_sid.log`

```
ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job 26
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

I am unable to link the ORA-01422 error with any of my code. I'm not doing any `fetch` here.

Comment: I don't think you are showing us the correct code (or error message). The error message references a line 8 which is apparently not in the procedure you posted. And *that* update statement could not throw *that* error message.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a script for SQL*Plus, there are two / misssing, so it does nothing at all:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE archtemp AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE ARCH_TEMP SET ARCH_DATE = SYSDATE; 
    COMMIT;
END archtemp;
/

VAR jobno NUMBER;
BEGIN
   DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(:jobno, 'archtemp;', SYSDATE, 'sysdate + 1/1440');
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I guess it's another job failing, not yours.

Comment: Even if this job is removed, i keep getting following error in the log

Comment: [I pressed Enter for new line and the comment is posted :) ]
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 8

Comment: Well, if you can (not a production machine), disable the other jobs and see what happens. Still get the errors in the log? No? Re-Enable the first job, wait. Repeat until the error reappears. Yes? Log in as a DBA and check ALL_JOBS for jobs running in another schema.

Comment: Thanks for your trip. There is one job which is causing the "recursive SQL ..." error but even after disabling all other jobs, my job(#26) is still failing with same error.

Comment: can you post the output of "select * from user_jobs where job=26"?

Comment: I posted it as an answer to this question

Comment: 'JOB','LOG_USER','PRIV_USER','SCHEMA_USER','LAST_DATE','LAST_SEC','THIS_DATE','THIS_SEC','NEXT_DATE','NEXT_SEC','TOTAL_TIME','BROKEN','INTERVAL','FAILURES','WHAT','NLS_ENV','MISC_ENV','INSTANCE'
127,'HRSA','HRSA','HRSA',09.09.2010 11:55:48,'11:55:48',,'',09.09.2010 12:03:48,'12:03:48',0,'N','sysdate + 1/1440',3,'archtemp;','NLS_LANGUAGE="'AMERICAN"' NLS_TERRITORY="'AMERICA"' NLS_CURRENCY="'$"' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY="'AMERICA"' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS="'.,"' NLS_DATE_FORMAT="'DD-MON-RR"' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE="'AMERICAN"' NLS_SORT="'BINARY"'','0102000200000000',0

Comment: Hmmm... nothing odd here... I must confess I'm running out of plausible ideas. Maybe there are check constraints on the table that do something *strange* that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do any data fetch here, but I guess some `ON UPDATE` trigger on `ARCH_TEMP` table might. Check it.

Comment: It's possible that ammoQ is right, then, perform a `select * from user_jobs where job = 26`, and see which one is actually failing. It should have `broken` status.

Comment: There are three other jobs but none of them is Broken or even failed once.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a SERVERERROR trigger (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468216/oracle-is-there-a-way-to-get-recent-sql-syntax-errors)) to try to catch the statement that is failing. But first, you could check the alert log. If recursive SQL is erroring, there may be a problem in the data dictionary.

Comment: I didn't get you about "SERVERERROR". I disabled all other jobs but still mine is failing

Comment: SERVERERROR is a type of trigger that can capture additional information when an error is returned. You are getting a TOO_MANY_ROWS error and you need to identify the SQL and table(s) involved. A trace (DBMS_MONITOR) should do the job as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in an explicit PL/SQL block as the WHAT parameter.

```
dbms_job.submit(v_jobno, 'begin archtemp; end;', sysdate, 'sysdate+1/1440');
```

Here's my test case, which seems to work fine:

```
create table arch_temp (
    arch_date date
    );

-- create row to test update
insert into arch_temp (arch_date) values (null);

create or replace procedure archtemp as
begin
    update arch_temp set arch_date = sysdate;
    commit;
end archtemp;
/

-- test everything works in isoloation

begin 
    archtemp; 
end;
/

select * from arch_temp;
-- arch_date = 10:49:34

select * from user_jobs;
-- no rows returned

declare
    v_jobno number;
begin
    dbms_job.submit(v_jobno, 'begin archtemp; end;', sysdate, 'sysdate+1/1440');
    commit;
    dbms_output.put_line('v_jobno: ' || to_char(v_jobno));
end;
/

-- dbms_output...
-- v_jobno: 50520

select * from user_jobs;

-- JOB 50520 returned
-- LAST_DATE = 10:51:11

select * from arch_temp;

-- ARCH_DATE = 10:51:11
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried solution by Nick Pierpoint as well but it didn't work for me
It looks something is wrong with LUCK because i tried the same thing on another machine having Oracle 9i and it failed!!!

Thank you all for your replies.

Regards

Comment: So you went through my example and it failed?

Comment: Yes, however, I used same script to create two jobs on a different service(9i) with two different tables and procedures and both worked well. My colleague created 1 job on 11g with DBA and it failed and and the other job on same service was created using USER which is running fine. I tried both with and without DBA on 10g and both failed.