# Django - Oracle backend error

Tags: django, oracle, oracle10g, django-orm, cx-oracle

I have the following model in Django:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    # some fields
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
```

I'm using Oracle 10g Database with Django 1.5 and cx_oracle 5.1.2. The issue here is when I try to create a new object in the admin interface (picking dates from the calendar), the following error is raised:

```
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

`syncdb` has created a `DATE` field in oracle for `start_date` and `end_date`. Does this look like a backend bug or am I doing something wrong?

I do have other models with `DateTimeField()` and they work fine when I persist new objects, the issue looks related to `DateField` itself.

**UPDATE:** I have checked the backend implementation, and in `backends/oracle/base.py` lines 513 to 516:

```
cursor.execute(
    "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'"
    " NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'"
    + (" TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'" if settings.USE_TZ else ''))
```

Executing this statement allows an insert statement to have literal values for `DATE` fields. I have checked the query generated by the backend and it is inserting `'2013-03-20'` in `start_date` and `end_date`. The date matches `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, so this in theory should work!

**UPDATE**: I believe my case is [related to cx_oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396241/cx-oracle-ora-01843-not-a-valid-month-with-unicode-parameter).

**UPDATE**: Since I still don't have a definite answer (although I'm almost sure it's cx_oracle that's causing this issue), I changed my `DateField` into a `DateTimeField` which translates into oracle's `TIMESTAMP` and works perfectly fine.

Comment: So just to be clear, you're checking the Oracle SYS tables for the SQL being run and seeing something like `TO_DATE('2013-03-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` in your insert?  From your question, it looks like `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`, which is different from the actual insert, though I don't know what effect this would have in this context.

Comment: No, because of the alter session statement setting `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, you can insert the date as a literal without to_date, which is the case when I check the SQL being executed.

Comment: Can you post the relevant SQL that is being run on the server that results in the `ORA-01843` error?

Comment: I don't have access to the system currently, but I have tried executing the SQL statement in an SQL client and it worked fine. I couldn't get the query from the database by the way, since it raised an error and wasn't executed I believe. I printed it in the console.

Comment: This might be useful in diagnosing your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468216/oracle-is-there-a-way-to-get-recent-sql-syntax-errors

Comment: What is the `cursor`? Is that a connection object or a recordset object?

Comment: Models.DateField() uses datetime.date [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField] In base.py lines, 182-191, it mentions how cx_oracle always returns datetime.datetime so it does some conversion. To confirm, you checked the query by turning on verbose output?

Comment: @JohnD I added a print statement in base.py in line 774 to print the queries and another print statement for the list generated by `self._param_generator(params)`; I wanted to see what's being passed to the DB just before it gets executed since it's an ORA error.

Comment: So, what SQL looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [jtiai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546062/jtiai) problem [description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269719/565525), I made following workaround - before calling any problematic sql-s (e.g. oracle 10.5.0.2 and 11.2.0.1, cx_oracle 5.1.2), reset NLS_DATE_FORMAT/NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT again - done in django/db/backends/oracle/base.py in method `def execute(...)`:

```
--- base.py 2013-10-31 12:19:24.000000000 +0100
+++ base_new.py 2013-10-31 12:20:32.000000000 +0100
@@ -707,6 +707,18 @@
         query = convert_unicode(query % tuple(args), self.charset)
         self._guess_input_sizes([params])
         try:
+            # BUG-WORKAROUND: ulr1-131031 
+            # https://stackoverflow.com/a/17269719/565525
+            # It's actually a bug in the Oracle 10.5.0.2 and 11.2.0.1. Bug can be reproduced as following:
+            #     - set NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT in session.
+            #     - Run any implicit or explicit TO_DATE conversion with unicode data.
+            #     - **Next implicit or explicit TO_TIMESTAMP with unicode data will trigger internal reset of timestamp format.**
+            #     - All consecutive TO_TIMESTAMP will fail and TO_CHAR of timestamp will produce invalid output.
+            self.cursor.execute(
+                "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'"
+                " NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'"
+                + (" TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'" if settings.USE_TZ else ''))
+
             return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
         except Database.IntegrityError as e:
             six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
```

Answer (score -2):

The cause of the error is you entered a date, but the month portion of the date was not a valid month. Oracle give resolutions for this problem.

**1** - Re-enter the date value using either a `MONTH` or `MON` format mask. The valid values for month are:

```
January
February
March
.......
//and soon
```

OR

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
.......
//and soon
```

**2** - if the above resolution is failed, use `to_date function` instead.

```
to_date( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )
```